# Opposite of honorary member

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Defining a honorary member as a person which isn't actually a member of an organization but is recognized as such by the organization because of his/her contributions to the organization or society as a whole, I am wondering if there exists a noun or an adjective used specifically to refer to the real members.

I am looking to use it in the following way:

> This mailing list is intended for both *real* and honorary members of our organization.

Why not just use real? I've thought about using real, standard or actual, but I feel like they all imply that one of the member categories is more important or otherwise superior to the other one, when for the matter at hand they are supposed to be considered equal.

Comment: "Members". You don't need an adjective to reinforce what the word already means alone.

Comment: Firstly, honorary members are as real as any other. Depending on the bye-laws of your "organization," the other categories probably are Full, Associate, Temporary, etc., together constituting the "paying members."

Comment: 'Fully paid-up' is an informal way of expressing @Kris's thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use "regular members" in contradistinction to "honorary members." Here is the relevant meaning of *regular* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **regular** *adj* ... **4 a :** constituted, conducted, scheduled, or done in conformity with established or prescribed usages, rules, or discipline

Depending on the type of organization it is and the qualifications for regular membership, you might use the term "dues-paying members" (where *dues-paying* simply means "paying regular membership dues") or "rank-and-file members" instead. The relevant definition of *rank and file* in the *Eleventh Collegiate* is this:

> **rank and file** *n* ... **2 :** the individuals who constitute the body of an organization, society, or nation as distinguished from the leaders

But "regular members" is probably the most inclusive and neutral term to use.

Answer (score 2):

There is no **general** answer (i.e. an answer that would be based on the meanings of words as defined in general-purpose dictionaries) that can be given to this question, apart from the obvious *non-honorary*, [suggested by](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/307464/466641) @user140086. If there is a word that can be used to denote all members of a particular organisation other than the honorary ones, it has to be a word that is explicitly defined in the bylaws of that organisation to have that precise meaning.

Using the word *real* for that purpose would have the implication that the honorary members are not really members of the organisation, which would make one wonder what was the point of admitting them as such. (This has already been observed in a comment by Kris.) Indeed, the honorary members could be insulted by the implication that they are not real members. While it may perhaps be understandable that the non-honorary members may sometimes be tempted to use *real* in this way when speaking informally, among themselves, its is not something that should ever appear in the organisation's formal communications. (It is not crucial to answering this question, but it should be noted, incidentally, that the differences between the honorary and other members vary greatly from organisation to organisation: at some places the honorary membership is largely nominal, but at others the honorary members may be involved in the actual activities of the organisation.)

The terms *regular* and *ordinary*, proposed elsewhere on this page, can mean the same as *non-honorary* **if** they are so defined in the bylaws of the organisation, but they cannot be assumed to have that precise meaning in the absence of such an organisation-specific, explicit definition. This is because different organisations have different classifications of members, and in some of them *regular* or *ordinary* may be used in contrast to, say, *associate, temporary, senior*, or *emeritus*, rather than in contrast to *honorary*.

So the only answer that can be given to this question is: look up the bylaws of the relevant organisation and use whatever term is defined there to have this meaning. If no such term can be found, then the only term that can reliably carry this precise meaning is *non-honorary*.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using [**ordinary**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ordinary) which means:

> With no special or distinctive features; normal.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

As Sven Yargs pointed out, you can distinguish members by using *fee-paying member* and *non fee-paying* member and an honorary member usually belongs to the latter.

However, if you really want to distinguish other *ordinary* members from an honorary member, you could consider using **non-honorary** member:

> The membership of any **non‐honorary member** shall be terminated upon
> failure by such member to pay the prescribed dues.

[[By-Laws of the Southeastern Museum Conference, Incorporated](http://www.semcdirect.net/Resources/Documents/Organization%20Info%20Doc/Council%20Documents/SEMC%20By%20Laws.pdf)]

*Non-honorary* is not broadly used, but in your example:

> This mailing list is intended for both honorary and **non-honorary / ordinary**
> members of our organization.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, just saying "member" is enough. It's the "honorary" before "member" that informs that a person's membership is something different than simply being a *member*. However, if the context would be aided by drawing a contrast to an "honorary member," "[**full-fledged member**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/full-fledged)" is fairly common for that purpose.

Comment: I  have worked for many membership organizations and this is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

In our chapter of the Synchonized Marching and New England Style Chowder Society we call such people ***active members***, to distinguish them from honorary, associate, retired or otherwise ornamental members.

While the latter degrees are invited to write checks in support of the society (NB, Canadians may write "cheques"; we also take plastic...) they are not expected to march or wash chowder bowls.

Comment: This terminology may work within a particular association, but different associations may use these terms differently. In some of them, for example, a retired member may be somebody who has retired from employment (and, because of that, perhaps entitled to a discount on the membership fees), but is fully active within the association.